# how to call function in ionic framework + angularjs?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I am using ionic framework to make android app .I am having cordova **5.1** version .first I create a project using command line **ionic start myApp tabs** .The I add android platform .Now I need to Communicate java code to javascript  code .Using google I found I need to make custom plugin .But I did not found any solution on google how we will create custom plugin .I found **ng-cordova** which give own plugin we can't make customize plugin .

I just need A **button** on UI .On click of that button I need to call **java** function having print some log on console .Then return success or error callback on JavaScript file

Could you please tell me how we will create a simple plugin in ionic ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, custom cordova plugins are painful because the official docs are not so great.

First of all we need to understand a custom plugin ***folder structure.***

[image]

1. wrapper - Name you want to give to your plugin
2. src - folder where your source code goes
3. android - since you are looking for android, an android folder is required
4. www - it contains the javascript functions that calls the java code.(using cordova)
5. plugin.xml - the very heart of the plugin, this files configures the plugin (adding permissions, copying files to platforms etc)

In your android folder create a CustomPlugin.java file.

```
package com.example.myplugin;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

public class CustomPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

   @Override
   public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if ("beep".equals(action)) {
        // print your log here... 
        callbackContext.success();
        return true;
    }
    return false;  // Returning false results in a "MethodNotFound" error.
    }
 }
```

Now we need to build a interface between javascript and java code.

Cordova provides a simple function for this.

```
exec(<successFunction>, <failFunction>, <service>, <action>, [<args>]);
```

---

create a `MycustomPlugin.js` file in `www` folder.

```
cordova.exec( successCallback,  ErrorCallBack, "service","action", []);
```

It is worth to know that,

*service -> Name of the java class*

*action -> action we want to call ( in this case "beep" see above code)*

Your MycustomPlugin.js file should look like this:

```
var MyPlugin = {
  PrintLog: function (successCallback, errorCallback, action) {
    cordova.exec(
            successCallback, // success callback function
            errorCallback, // error callback function
            'CustomPlugin', // mapped to our native Java class called
            action, // with this action name , in this case 'beep'
            []  )// arguments, if needed
  }
}
module.exports = MyPlugin;
```

Lastly you need to configure your `plugin.xml` file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <plugin xmlns="http://www.phonegap.com/ns/plugins/1.0"
            id="com.example.plugin"
            version="0.0.1">        
      <name>Cordova Plugin</name> 

      <engines>
        <engine name="cordova" version=">=3.4.0"/>
      </engines> 

      <js-module src="www/MycustomPlugin.js" name="CustomPlugin">
        <clobbers target="window.MycustomPlugin" />
      </js-module>    
    <platform name="android">

        <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
           <feature name="CustomPlugin">
              <param name="android-package" value="com.example.myplugin.CustomPlugin"/>
           </feature>
        </config-file>

       <source-file src="src/android/CustomPlugin.java" target-dir="src/com/example/myplugin"/>     

   </platform>
</plugin>
```

now add this plugin to your project. **myApp** (the one you created) 
using `cordova plugin add /path/to/your/custom/plugin`

And in $ionicPlatform.ready function call your java code from javascript

```
   window.MycustomPlugin.PrintLog(function(res){
     //success
   }, function(err){
        //error
   }, "beep")
```

Comment: Hello But I am using ionic framwork it is work on ionic

Comment: Yes I know, Ionic is built on cordova, so it dosen't matter. It will work on ionic as well.
Also if you want to go in more details check this http://devgirl.org/2013/09/17/how-to-write-a-phonegap-3-0-plugin-for-android/

Answer (score 0):

I found your error:

```
TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings
    at Object.win32.join (path.js:233:13)
```

It was fixed by appending the end tag

```
</platform>
</plugin>
```