# Add External Jar Library to Build Cordova Plugin (Ionic Framework)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Is that possible to add external jar library like android volley library when build cordova plugin for ionic framework, I have try build cordova plugin like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31738976/3167956), but in that tutorial it just use Android Core abilities, not external android libraries, is there a way to add it and is it possible ?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can use [dependency libraries in cordova plugins for Android](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html#adding-dependency-libraries)

On the config.xml you have to add it like this

```
<lib-file src="src/android/libs/yourLibName.jar"/>
```

The recommended way is adding the library using Gradle (if possible). Volley doesn't seems to be compatible, but you can use this compatible fork

```
<framework src="com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.19" />
```